# Laravel API authenticate user - logged in user vs api user/client

Tags: laravel

OK this may sound lame ;-) I am getting a bit turned around on this.

I have an application (will eventually be mobile/using api) which has a company table. Then i have the ability to view and see info on this company and favor/like the company (company_user).

The api will have a route api/company return json data for this company. If the user is logged in then it will also show if liked by user or not.

How would you set up the authentication for the API? I would want the auth client to register/login but this is not the user that would log in via mobile? what would my company Resource or company Controller look like?

Answer (score 0):

Check out JWT. You login and get a "token" which authenticates the user. Works on apps and websites. We use https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Comment: i am using Laravel 5.5 Api built-in resources and likely Passport